# Where is the definition of the acquire operation in the C++ 20?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, atomic, memory-barriers, stdatomic

I am reading the [std::memory_order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) on the cppreference.com and the [C++ 20 specification](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/releases/download/n4861/n4861.pdf). I can't find the definition of the terms, "acquire operation" and "release operation".

The first document recursively defines the terms, saying "Atomic load with memory_order_acquire or stronger is an acquire operation." and "memory_order_acquire: A load operation with this memory order performs the acquire operation on the affected memory location."

And the second document seems to use the terms without any definition. It begins to use the terms, saying "A synchronization operation on one or more memory locations
is either a consume operation, an acquire operation, a release operation, or both an acquire and release operation."

So I googled and found [LINUX KERNEL MEMORY BARRIERS](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt), which clearly defines the terms like the following.

> (5) ACQUIRE operations.
>
> This acts as a one-way permeable barrier.  It guarantees that all memory
> operations after the ACQUIRE operation will appear to happen after the
> ACQUIRE operation with respect to the other components of the system.
> ACQUIRE operations include LOCK operations and both smp_load_acquire()
> and smp_cond_load_acquire() operations.
>
> Memory operations that occur before an ACQUIRE operation may appear to
> happen after it completes.
>
> An ACQUIRE operation should almost always be paired with a RELEASE
> operation.

Is this definition exactly the same thing what the authors meant for the term "acquire operation"?

Comment: The standard describes the requirements. If it can describe requirements by consistently using a term, it doesn't need to define it. Look at the definition of *happens- before*, that describes the required behaviours of the memory orders

Comment: @Caleth In C++ standard, most specifications begins by defining basic terms and rules and expands by adding new ones based on the previously defined ones, as in Mathematics. Did you notice Set theory terms such as "transitive relation"? Anyway I just want to be sure on the meaning of the acquire and release operation. Can you feedback for my yes or no question above? I'm a novice on the low level computer programming.

Comment: An acquire operation is unlike a ptr addition or a float multiplication: the later operations are defined directly, and useful as such, as such; *an atomic memory order is useless as such*, and can only be conceived WRT to other atomic operations. In fact the whole thread sync stuff is useless as such, you don't lock and unlock a mutex in single thread!

Comment: @curiousguy, you need to see the linked document, Linux kernel memory barriers. The compiler or the microcode interpreter inside the CPU can reorder instructions. Google for ```MFENCE``` for example.

Comment: @relent95 The freedom of compilers are mirroring those of the various CPU which are integrated in the language semantics. Let's focus on what the CPU is doing. The CPU isn't "reordering instructions" as if by rewrite of the code, the CPU is trying to do as much as possible operations early to avoid starving computation units, so loads can be performed early and stores can be committed (commit = made visible to all execution units) later. (Reordering of the queue of the marker where you let that tired pregnant mom pass is very different.) I don't like the explanation in term of reordering.

Comment: The CPU must take great care to avoid breaking PO (program order) and so doesn't just "reorder loads and stores" willy-nilly, which would break all code. Modern CPU, more precisely modern execution units, optimistically do stuff, both external (loads, going to outside the memory system) and internal (computations, staying inside the math units). If that optimism wasn't justified, that data is thrown out.

Comment: F.ex. given pure functions, `if(cond(x)) y=costly(x);` can be run as `r=costly(x); if(cond(x)) r=y;` if the operation `costly(x)` are non-trivial and not too costly, and there are available execution units). Is that count a "reordering"? I would call that "starting independent potentially useful computations earlier". Note that since common asm instr that do computations are almost always nearly pure: pure (no SE = side effect) beside condition flags, but can cause exceptions, the CPU must a) virtualize the condition flags; b) catch and hide the exception until the `cond(x)` is proven true.

Comment: So you see the CPU is never just "reordering" anything, as if by copy-paste of the individual asm instructions, or of smaller, each elementary operations (assuming you split a x86 or a 68000 instr into more elementary ops like loads, computations, tests, loads...). Naive "reorder" would wreck everything starting with FLAGS and all stateful stuff! There is a whole layer only to provide only valid premature executions, even on very "weakly ordered" CPU. Representing that abstractly and usefully in an higher lever language is hard. Even if you know that, it probably even harder than you think!

Comment: What is the definition of addition in Peano? It isn't defined as a textbook function in a school book.

Answer (score 7):

The definition you have cited isn't recursive, it simply is a definition; however, it isn't properly formatted.
The standard usually uses *italic text* to indicate when a term is defined, and I believe this should be applied here:

> `memory_order​::​acquire`, `memory_order​::​acq_rel`, and `memory_order​::​seq_cst`: a load operation performs an *acquire operation* on the affected memory location.

- [[atomics.order]](https://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.order#lib:memory_order_acquire)

All the properties of such an acquire operation (most importantly, release operations synchronize with it) are defined elsewhere, including in the next paragraph:

> An atomic operation `A` that performs a release operation on an atomic object `M` synchronizes with an atomic operation `B` that performs an acquire operation on `M` and takes its value from any side effect in the release sequence headed by `A`.

- [[atomics.order] p2](https://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.order#2)

*Synchronize with* and its effects are defined in [[intro.races]](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#def:synchronize_with).

In short, a load using `std::memory_order::acquire` is an *acquire operation*, and this means that release operations synchronize with it. This synchronization is well-defined. Nothing is recursive; however, the formatting is misleading.

---

*Note: this answer mostly relates to the C++ standard, but the same logic can be applied to the cppreference article as well.*

*Note: I've opened an [an editorial issue](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/6567) about this in the C++ draft repository.*

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but IMHO the definition of the term "synchronizes with" uses the term "acquire operation" and "release operation", so it's still recursive.

Comment: The Linux memory barriers document defines an acquire operation as "a memory barrier variant which guarantees that all memory operations after the ACQUIRE operation will appear to happen after the ACQUIRE operation with respect to the other components of the system". And maybe I can interpret it as "An acquire operation is an operation which guarantees that no reads or writes in the current thread can be reordered before the operation", quoting part of the "no reads or writes in the current thread can be reordered before this load" in the cppreference article. Am I right?

Comment: Sorry for spammy questions, but I think C++ standard partially defines the acquire and release operations, saying "Informally, performing a release operation on A forces prior side effects on other memory locations to become visible to other threads that later perform a consume or an acquire operation on A.". Am I right?

Comment: @relent95: Yes, that's the standard meaning of those terms and isn't specific to C++.  https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/.  The ISO C++ standard does define the formal rules for what ops are required to see what, so in that sense it does define acquire / release.  If an acquire load never syncs with anything, there's no actual requirement to order anything, and ISO C++ avoids specifying anything in terms of local reordering of accesses to coherent cache, only the formal model which is based on visibility rules.

Comment: @relent95 I'm not sure where you're still seeing the recursion. The term "synchronizes with" uses the term "acquire operation", and "acquire operation" is (seemingly) defined as an operation involving `std::memory_order::acquire`. Where is the recursion? The cppreference article basically just summarizes what the standard says in various sections about the effects of atomic operations. (This comes from "synchronize with", "happens before", and other relations)

Comment: @Jan Schultke The C++ standard says "For example, an
atomic store-release synchronizes with a load-acquire that takes its value from the store " and the cppreference article says "If an atomic store in thread A is a release operation, an atomic load in thread B from the same variable is an acquire operation, and the load in thread B reads a value written by the store in thread A, then the store in thread A synchronizes-with the load in thread B.". I think both of them define the "synchronize with" relation using the existing(or predefined) terms, acquire and release operations.

Comment: @relent95 why do you think that those terms are predefined (outside the standard) rather than being defined by [atomics.order] paragraph 1? Sure, the formatting is misleading, but it's overall clear that the bullets in that paragraph act as a definition, and that definition wouldn't be recursive. It wouldn't be the first time that someone forgets to add `\defn{}` formatting to a definition. It happens quite often actually.

Comment: If I was going to mark some instance of "acquire" as being the definition, I would choose the earlier appearance in [intro.races p3], right after "synchronization operations".  Effectively this introduces "acquire" as a particular category of synchronization operation, whose members and properties will be stated later.

Comment: @NateEldredge I don't think [intro.races] p3 is normative. It just seems to be a general overview over library features, memory orders, etc. but has no normative content. I don't think it's suitable for a definition, and it's not like it defines anything; it merely mentions terms.

Comment: @JanSchultke: Well, the point I make in the answer is that I don't think "acquire" really has, or needs, a definition.  It's just an arbitrary string that identifies a particular set of operations.

Comment: @NateEldredge "acquire" doesn't, but "acquire operation" should have a definition. [intro.races] p3 doesn't offer anything compelling that could act as that.

Comment: @Jan Schultke The [atomics.order (1.4)] defines the ```memory_order​::​acquire```, saying when a load operation(such as the ```atomic::load()```) called with the ```order``` argument as the ```memory_order::acquire``` performs an acquire operation on the affected memory location. This means the calling thread sees side effects of memory accesses(to any address) sequenced before a "release operation"(code written before a ```xxx.store(memory_order::release);``` for example) on the same atomic variable in another thread. How can you deduce this from that paragraph?

Comment: @relent95 [atomics.order] p1.4 simultaneously defines `std::memory_order::acquire` and gives an operation involving it the name "acquire operation". Later paragraphs describe what acquire/release operations do.

Comment: @JanSchultke The point is that neither acquire not release "does" anything (unlike say sin, cos, tan). Only a proper combination of these performs anything useful.

Comment: @curiousguy this discussion is getting off-topic and no longer relates to the post. This Q&A is not about usefulness of terms, it's about where a definition is located in the C++ standard.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think of "acquire" as really having any meaning of its own.  It's just a tag that the standard associates with a certain set of operations.  Then the standard can describe properties of this set of operations by referring to them collectively as "acquire operations".

So in that sense, it doesn't require a definition.

This is sort of suggested by the first instance of the term in the standard, in [intro.races p2]:

> The library defines a number of atomic operations (Clause 31) and operations on mutexes (Clause 32)
> that are specially identified as synchronization operations. These operations play a special role in making
> assignments in one thread visible to another. A synchronization operation on one or more memory locations
> is either a consume operation, an acquire operation, a release operation, or both an acquire and release
> operation.

So here "synchronization operation" is introduced as a more-or-less arbitrary tag that will be applied to certain types of operations.  Then it is further subdivided into "consume", "acquire", and "release" which, in context, are also arbitrary tags.

If you really think that "acquire" needs a definition, then I would define it in either of the following ways:

1. Search the standard and make a list of all instances where an operation is stated to be an acquire operation.  Then define "acquire operation" as "an operation appearing in that list".
2. Search the standard and make a list of all properties that acquire operations are stated to have.  Then define "acquire operation" as "an operation having all the properties in that list".

---

To give an analogy that is *somehow even more nerdy* than sitting around parsing an ISO language standard: it's like asking where the term "thallid" is defined in the rules of *Magic: The Gathering*.  Okay, in-universe it's some kind of fungus creature, but that's irrelevant to gameplay.  All a player needs to know is that certain cards are marked as being thallids, and other cards may say that they interact with thallids in specific ways.  So in that sense, the definition of "thallid" is, implicitly, "a card that has the words 'Summon Thallid' on it".  (To be pedantic, "or any other entity, such as a token, that is stated to be a thallid").  And while this might seem to be circular, it really isn't.

Comment: By design, the set of visibility rules required by ISO C++ acquire and release operations are consistent with the standard definitions (in terms of preventing reordering of a core's accesses to coherent cache: https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/).  But yes it's fine for the formalism in the C++ standard to leave that implicit, since it doesn't mention "reordering" anywhere except in notes.  Just being a tag, similar to terms they invent like "strongly happens before", is my understanding of the C++ standard's approach.

Comment: _a tag that the standard associates with … Then the standard can describe properties … by referring to … So in that sense, it doesn't require a definition._ I'd say the situation with _object_ or value categories is similar, but they have italicized «definitions»

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Like `<` in arithmetic. It doesn't have a "definition" directly, it has properties described by axioms.